# The problem is that if the input is for example 15 it asks again and never works

Tags: python

The input keeps asking again and again.
Even after I put in 15, 30 or 60.

```
stones = int(input('stones'))
while stones not in ['15', '30', '60']:
    print("Your number of stones needs to be 15, 30 or 60")
    stones = int(input('stones'))

while stones > 0:
    print('yay')
```

Comment: `stones` is an `int`, there are no ints in `['15', '30', '60']`, they are all strings.

Comment: How do I solve this?

Comment: while stones not in [15, 30, 60]:

Comment: Try to think carefully about your logic. Where your code says `stones = int(input('stones'))`, what is the intended purpose? What kind of thing will `stones` be? Therefore, what kind of thing should you try to compare `stones` to? Therefore, what should you put into your list for the `not in` comparison? You should not need someone else to answer these questions for you; if you do, it is because you have not properly studied the fundamentals. Programming is essentially about *thinking*.

Answer (score 3):

You converted your input to `int`, but then you're comparing it to strings.  Do:

```
stones = int(input('stones'))
while stones not in [15, 30, 60]:
    print("Your number of stones needs to be 15, 30 or 60")
    stones = int(input('stones'))
```

Comment: Thanks it works now